# allow_unknown parameter ignored

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I want to avoid the global planner to plan its paths through the unknown because it is not working for my case. So as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn) I set the paramter allow_unknown to false. So I created a yaml named **global_planner.yaml** file like this:

```
NavfnROS:
   allow_unknown: false
   default_tolerance: 5
```

In the launch file for the move_base node I added a line to load the parameters:

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" respawn="true">
   <rosparam file="$(find multi_robot_simulation)/config/global_planner.yaml" command="load" />
</node>
```

The parameter also shows up in the parameter server:

```
rosparam get /move_base/NavfnROS/allow_unknown
```

returns **false**, as expected.
So, whats wrong here???

Thanks for any help!
Micha

**UPDATE:**

I just pulled the navigation package from github to do some tests with the code. I realized the parameter is read just fine! The path planner still plans its path through unknown! Why??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215538/allow_unknown-parameter-ignored/) by [Micha Sende](https://answers.ros.org/users/23012/micha-sende/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess next time I should read the parameter description more carefully:
http://wiki.ros.org/navfn?distro=indigo#line-314

The same issue has been described here:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/261

The parameter in question can be found here:
http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles#ObstacleCostmapPlugin

---

Originally posted by [Micha Sende](https://answers.ros.org/users/23012/micha-sende/) with karma: 65 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-08-11**:
Is this solved then?

**Comment by [Micha Sende](https://answers.ros.org/users/23012/micha-sende/) on 2015-08-12**:
Yes, but I cannot accept my own answer.

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-02-19**:
To make this a bit more than a link-only answer: The parameter description for `allow_unknown` that is linked above says: *"if you are using a layered costmap_2d costmap with a voxel or obstacle layer, you must also set the track_unknown_space param for that layer to be true..."*